# Viewing Counters in GCD Summary

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Counter defined in a DoFn written with Beam 0.7.0-SNAPHOT:

```
private final Counter elementCounter = Metrics.counter(MyDoFn.class, "foobar");
```

...but unlike in Frances Perry's [demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owTuuVt6Oro) this value doesn't appear in the Google Cloud Dataflow monitoring UI.

Do I need to override `populateDisplayData` to be able to view my Counter?

Comment: Do you have a Dataflow job ID I can look at?

Comment: 2017-04-20_11_05_50-3219023862435291262 Thank you for looking into this!

Comment: OK. The workaround is to use the Aggregator API instead of Metrics - https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/core/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Aggregator.java - Metrics do not work yet in streaming Dataflow pipelines on Beam. Can you try that please?

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me, but my understanding is that the Aggregator API is going to be removed in the near future. Is there an issue I can follow for streaming Metrics in GCD or should I create one?

Comment: I couldn't find an external issue for supporting Metric's in streaming Dataflow pipelines. Please feel free to create one in the Beam JIRA https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM

Comment: I've created an issue here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2059

Comment: Unfortunately the Aggregators API was removed before this could be resolved.

Comment: Yes, right now the situation with metrics for streaming pipelines is awkward :( Your workaround would be to use an older version of the Beam SDK that still has the Aggregators API. Beam First Stable Release will not include Aggregators API, instead at some point Metrics in streaming pipelines will start working properly and that's when you can switch to that.